# How to identify parts of c++ code in disassembled .exe file code

Tags: c++, x86-64

As part of an assignment I was given a simple .exe game file and I am supposed to disassemble it and add a 'cheat'. I'm using IDA Pro Free to disassemble. What I've gotten is thousands and thousands of lines of disassembled code most of which seems to have been made by the compiler.
Do you have any advice as to how to find the pertinent (non-compiler) code? Should I be using a different disassembler?
Thanks

Comment: What makes you think *any* of it is "non-compiler" code (whatever that is) ?

Comment: It is very hard and mostly impossible to determine the source code (c++ or otherwise) used to generate a compiled binary.

Comment: What do mean by "non-compiler" code?

Comment: If your task is to insert a cheat then you don't need to go beyond disassembling. You simply need to find a place that gets executed (probably some input handling code) and insert a subroutine. I'm assuming if you're given this task that you know some x86-64 assembly